# Save user favorites

Tags: .net, configuration, configuration-files

In my application I need to display items to the user. 
He can mark some items as favorites. I need to display those differently.

How can I save the favorites on the user's computer? I need something like a config entry ... but I need to change that as the user add/remove the favorites. Do you think that I should save that in registry ... or on the disk in a separate file?

Does .net offers some support for such situations?

Thanks, 
Radu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Yes, the .NET Framework makes it very easy to save user-level settings in your application.** You should not save them directly to the Registry, and it's not necessary to write code yourself to save the settings to a file. The documentation for this feature can be found [here on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397750.aspx).

If you're using C#, there's an excellent introduction here: [Using Settings in C#](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa730869.aspx).

If you're using VB.NET, there's an excellent introduction here: [Application settings in VB.NET](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/vb/appsettings2005.aspx).